# How to use "as … as"

Tags: conjunctions

> A. This company progresses as rapidly as it is impressing all people nowadays.
>
> B. This company progresses fast so that all people are being impressed nowadays.

Which one sounds more natural?

Comment: I wonder whether you meant that the company is progressing at the same speed at which it impresses people (as rapidly as), or simply that the company is progressing quickly, because it impresses people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those sounds natural.

In the first, you are not using the `as {modifier} as` pattern correctly.

**The cheetah is almost *as fast as* an automobile.**

In the second, you are not using the `so that` pattern correctly.

**We took the express, *so that* we could arrive on time.**

With your example:
**The company is progressing rapidly *because* it is impressing everyone these days.**

Its rapid progress is a result of its impressiveness.

**The company is progressing *so rapidly that* it is impressing everyone these days.**

Its impressiveness is a result of its rapid progress.

Comment: +1 *all people* is so weird, people may give you an interesting look if you uttered that. In case it was subtle enough not for the OP to understand, I pointed it out. :)

Comment: @[backwards]M.A. Ramezani: Indeed. It's impossible to intuit the difference between "all people" and "everyone".